# How to use multiprocessing for a Python for loop with a break statement?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

How to parallelize a for loop which has an if condition in it. If that condition is met, then there is no need to continue with the loop. It would be great if I could use multiprocessing for this.

```
for i in xrange(N):
    x = do_something_with()
    if x == 0:
        break
```

Can the above code be parallelized in Python?

Comment: About this `x`.... is the break condition dependent on something calculated in the subprocess or is it just a condition known in the parent?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the do_something_with() function?

Comment: My mistake it can be another variable than returns a value to be stored in x. Edited the question to reflect this change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can terminate a `multiprocessing.Pool` while jobs are active and it will kill the child processes. If you can generate your parameters in advance, `imap_unordered` can be used to pull in results and terminate the pool when the condition is met. Subprocesses processing other jobs in the pool are killed so they will not return other results.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def worker(x):
    print('work item', x)
    time.sleep(x)
    result = x - 5
    if result == 0:
        print('termination condition')
    print('work item', x, 'done')
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool(4)
    for result in p.imap_unordered(worker, range(20), chunksize=1):
        if result == 0:
            print('terminating')
            p.terminate()
            break
    print('done')
```

Results in

```
work item 0
work item 1
work item 0 done
work item 4
work item 3
work item 2
work item 1 done
work item 5
work item 2 done
work item 6
work item 3 done
work item 7
work item 4 done
work item 8
termination condition
work item 5 done
work item 9
terminating
done
```

Notice that some jobs were started but not completed.